# getUserMedia - depth stream extension

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia, mediastream

How do I access the properties of depth stream tracks through `getUserMedia()`? The properties I'm trying to get are `principalPointX, principalPointY, focalLengthX, focalLengthY` from [media tracks](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-depth/#def-constraint-principalPointX)

The documentation says I need to set `depth` to true, so when I do that, I get an error that forces me to set a `video`:

`(index):20 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getUserMedia' on 'Navigator': At least one of audio and video must be requested`

When I try to do this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, depth: true})
   .then(stream => {

   video.srcObject = stream;
   console.log(stream);

}).catch(console.error)
```

`stream` doesn't return any of the properties I am trying to get like `principalPointX`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These properties have been removed from the specs: https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-depth/#mediatracksettings-dictionary Also, while I can't test because I haven't access to a depth camera myself, I think it would be in `stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings()`  that you should retrieve this enum (which should only have `videoKind: 'depth'` if my understanding of the specs is correct.

Comment: Does this mean these are properties that I will not be able to use since it's been deprecated?

Comment: Well at least Chromium just removed it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=939722 now, do you even have access to such a DepthTrack? At the end of [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=616098) they say it's still under a startup flag.

Comment: I was hoping to create my own depth track from my phone camera through `getUserMedia()` and then access the depth track which would ideally have the properties like `focalLengthX`. Perhaps that's not how it works.

I tried `stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings()` and `stream.getTracks()[0].getSettings()` and both return an object like:
```{aspectRatio: 1.33333333333
deviceId: "2fcbe5cbbbf21e05a5c63602f63f7aa367e76ad5164de04f323be2d"
frameRate: 30.0000305175
groupId: "1597b58064afe71b4204d0f41b6f5b28fb79bb11d098030cd744d3"
height: 480
resizeMode: "none"
width: 640}```